# CreateSemaphoreEx Security Attribute vs Access Mask

Tags: c++, windows, security

The [CreateSemaphoreEx API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682446%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on the Windows platform has the following parameters:

LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpSemaphoreAttributes, and
DWORD dwDesiredAccess

I understand that they both serve to control access, however, I am not sure about their relationships and the differences between them. For example, If I set dwDesiredAccess to SYNCHRONIZE, but I create a security attribute with an empty DACL (i.e. no access at all), then how does that work together? If anyone can share information on the purposes of these parameters and how they interact together, that would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the object already exists:

- The `lpSemaphoreAttributes.lpSecurityDescriptor` parameter is ignored.
- The `dwDesiredAccess` parameter determines what access rights are given to the new handle returned from the function.  If these access rights are incompatible with the security permissions on the object, the call will fail with `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`.

If the object does not already exist:

- The `lpSemaphoreAttributes.lpSecurityDescriptor` parameter determines what security permissions are assigned to the newly created object.  If a security descriptor is not provided, default permissions are used.
- The `dwDesiredAccess` parameter determines what access rights are given to the new handle returned from the function.  These rights are *not* restricted by the security permissions on the newly created object.  Conceptually, the handle to the object is opened *before* the new permissions are applied.

So if you specify a DACL with an empty ACL (thus implicitly denying access to everybody) then the only way to access that object is via the handle that was created with the object, or a duplicate of that handle.  It will not be possible to open the object again, even from the same process, unless you first change the permissions to allow you to do so.

Note that other security rules do still apply when creating an object.  For example, you can't obtain the `ACCESS_SYSTEM_SECURITY` access right, even to a newly created object, unless you have the `SE_SECURITY_NAME` privilege.

It should also be emphasized that when you access an object using an existing open handle, only the handle's access rights are checked, not the current security permissions on the object.  If you obtained a particular access right when you opened the handle, it does not matter if the security permissions on the object have since been changed to deny you that right.

Conversely, if the handle was not opened with the access permission that you need to perform a given operation, you cannot perform that operation using that handle, even if the security permissions on the object give you the right to do so.

That is why the `dwDesiredAccess` parameter is so important; if you leave out a right that a particular operation needs, that operation will fail, but if you ask for too broad a set of rights, you might be denied access.  Luckily, in most cases, the documentation is straightforward, so it just takes a bit of attention to detail.

Comment: In response to "these rights are not restricted by the security permissions on the newly created object," I have noticed that if I create a new semaphore with SYNCHRONIZE access and call DuplicateHandle with SYNCHRONIZE|SEMAPHORE_MODIFY_STATE to pick up additional access, the DuplicateHandle fails if I have an empty DACL security permission set for the initial semaphore creation, but succeeds if the default security permission was used. Doesn't this imply that the rights can be restricted by the security permissions on the newly created object?

Comment: I'd have to double-check, but I believe that if you use the `DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS` option, the duplicate handle will receive the same access rights as the original handle without the security on the object being re-checked.  In any case, the *original* handle will still not be affected by the permissions.

Comment: (Obviously, if you are requesting additional access rights, they will have to be validated against the security permissions.  Otherwise that would be a trivial elevation of privilege vulnerability.)

Comment: If I use `DuplicateHandle` without `DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS` and the original semaphore creation had an empty DACL, the duplication succeeds. So this looks like this doesn't trigger the security permission check. Perhaps they realize that it's the same permission as the original and special-case that?

Comment: In that case, I suspect you'll find you can also drop access rights without triggering a permission check, i.e., only adding additional rights requires one.  It sounds reasonable, at any rate!  Note that ordinarily you should not need to add rights to a duplicated handle, the usual practice is for the original handle to have all of the access rights you need.  If you want multiple handles for some reason, with different access rights, it would probably be preferable to start with a handle that has all the rights and reduce those rights by duplication rather than the other way around.

Comment: "*Conceptually* the handle to the object is opened before the new permissions are applied"? To clarify this, the object is created with its security descriptor well before a handle is opened. But the object manager knows the handle is being opened for a newly created object, so it skips the access check (except accessing the SACL still requires `SeSecurityPrivilege`).